# Which solution to the integral $\int \frac {dx}{x \sqrt {x^2-1}}$ is correct and why?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I have this integral: $$\int \frac {dx}{x \sqrt {x^2-1}}.$$ I solved it like this: $$ \sqrt {x^2-1} = t \to x = \sqrt {t^2+1} \to $$ $$dx = \frac {t}{\sqrt {t^2+1}}\,dt .$$ Solving for t: $$ \int \frac {dt}{t^2+1} = \arctan(t) + c .$$ In the solution I have, however, it is solved in another way: $$ x = \sec(t), \ \sqrt{x^2-1}=\tan(t), $$ $$dx=\sec(t)\tan(t)\,dt \to $$ $$\int \frac {\sec(t)\tan(t)} {\sec(t)\tan(t)}\,dt= \int dt = t +c= \operatorname{arcsec}(x) + c.$$ Which solution is correct and why?

Comment: I replaced the t with the equivalent expression in x. My problem is that I have two different solutions which seem both correct to me.

Comment: Why is the second one incorrect then?

Comment: And what about x<-1 ?

Answer (score 6):

Both your answers are correct but you didn't finish the first one, you still have $t$ in it instead of $x$, that would give $\arctan(\sqrt{x^2-1})$.

You can verify that this is equal to $\operatorname{arcsec}(x)$ on 
$\mathbb R^+$.

On $\mathbb R^-$ you have the sign to change too $\pi-\arctan(...)$

Answer (score 1):

In both of your solutions, you make the assumption that $x>1$. In the first one, this happens when you write $x=\sqrt{t^2+1}$ instead of $x=-\sqrt{t^2+1}$. In the second one, you're implicitly taking $t\in(0,\pi/2)$ which leads you to $\sqrt{x^2-1}=\tan(t)$ and not $\sqrt{x^2-1}=-\tan(t)$. Both of your answers are correct in the interval $x>1$ because $\arctan\left(\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)=\operatorname{arcsec}(x)$ for $x>1$.

So, to consider the case $x<-1$, in the first solution, you instead take $x=-\sqrt{t^2+1}$, and for the second, we need $t\in(\pi/2,\pi)$ which makes $\tan(t)<0$ and $\sqrt{x^2-1}=-\tan(t)$. Because $\operatorname{arcsec}(-x)=\pi-\operatorname{arcsec}(x)$, there is a compact way to write the final asnwer without the need for branches:
$$\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\operatorname{arcsec}\left(|x|\right)+C $$

Answer (score 0):

If you differentiate $\operatorname{arcsec} x$, you get $1/\sqrt{1-x^2}$.  So it's not correct.

Trying the first, we get $(\arctan\sqrt{x^2-1})'=1/x^2(1/2)1/(\sqrt{x^2-1})(2x)=1/(x\sqrt{x^2-1})$.

So the first is correct.

I think, in your calculation for the second one, you would get $\sqrt{x^2-1}=|\tan x|$.

Comment: For some reason, although `\arctan x`, `\arcsin x`, and `\arccos x` format nicely, you need `\operatorname{arcsec} x` to duplicate the format.

Comment: Your welcome, @Chris. Glad you found my edit useful.

Comment: @amWhy yes I did.  That is odd.

Comment: arccot, and arccsc, also need don't format nicely with a single backslash.  In linear algebra, despite how nicely `\det` formats, to write rank(A) or span$(\{x, y, z\})$, one needs to precede what one wants to serve as a function/operator (e.g., foo(z)) by explicitly writing `operatorname{foo}(z)`.  Kind of a pain, sometimes.

Comment: @amWhy I use `\operatorname` all the time.  Big pain in the butt.  Sometimes there's probably a better way, and I just don't know what it is yet.  Like in integrals, for `$\operatorname dx$`.  Just to straighten up the d.  Any suggestions?  Thanks for the heads up, BTW.

Comment: Yes there is a way to declare an operator/function (say it's "foo" at the start of a post, which one can then use throughout that post by merely using `\foo`.  I haven't used for a while but I've just asked around, and can dredge up older posts of mine that used it.  Ahh, you're in luck: moderator [@quid just responded in the chatroom CRUDE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53921174#53921174). So you don't have to chase a link: "The syntax is \DeclareMathOperator{NameOfCommand}{WhatIsDisplayed} It needs to be put in dollars. It's better to not have it at the very, very start."

Comment: @amWhy much appreciated.

Comment: My guess that might look, in a long string of arcsec's that might look like `$\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsec}{\operatorname{arcsec}$`  A bit long, but if you ever find yourself in need of using an operator **a lot** in a post,that not defined in mathjax as \operator, in this case, you could proceed through the rest of the post using `\arcsec".

Comment: @amWhy makes sense.  I'll have to try it.

Comment: it seems even simpler than that: you can use `$\DeclareMathOperator{arcsec}{arcsec}$`.  Then you can format as you usually would most trig functions, in the rest of the post: `\arcsec(x)`.

Comment: @amWhy Hi.  I recently discovered, btw, that you can type `\rm` for `\operatorname`.  Just thought I woulld bring this to your attention, as per our discussion.